# Loop through all files in a given subdirectory, name the output by the looped file

Tags: shell-script, rename, for

I have thousands of  *csv files in a certain subdirectory.

There's a simple in line executable which I use to work with these files, which I pipe into a new file:

```
executable file1.csv standard.csv > output_file1.csv
```

I would like to create a for loop to do this not just for `file1.csv`, but for all files in that subdirectory.

I would try something like this:

```
for file in *.csv
do
    # run executable on "$file" and output 
    executable $file standard.csv > output
done
```

I think this will work, but how do I name each output `output_` + `$file` +`.csv`?

Comment: My answer has been edited out of recognition, so I have deleted it

Comment: The entire point of SE is that the community can improve answers by editing them for form, content, edge cases, and reliability.  And the comment you ascribe to me was not of my origin in the first place.

Comment: @Bruno9779 I saw nothing wrong with your original answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to Bruno9779 for the original draft of this answer.  Not sure why it was self-deleted, as it was a pretty good answer:

You have pretty much done it yourself:

```
destinationDir="/destination/path/here/"
if cd "$destinationDir"; then
    for file in *.csv;  do
        # run executable on "$file" and output 
        executable "$file" standard.csv > "${destinationDir}/output_${file}.csv"
    done
else
    echo "Unable to change to working directory."
fi
```

Just remember to quote filenames with variables.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with @Bruno9779's answer

Comment: Generally speaking, no, but there were small issues that were immediately apparent.  For example, he or she or other admonished to quote filenames, but left the first instance of `$file` unquoted.  Those sorts of things are why I edited the answer - it was a pretty good answer, but had room for improvement, which is the entire point of this site.  Since the original author saw fit to delete the answer entirely, I opted to add a little sanity-checking and the like as I reposted it -- with credit to its origin, I would like to point out.

Comment: Yes, I was improving the answer, when a "realized" changed into a "Relize" tipped me off and I just deleted everything.

Comment: "Unable to to" might well be a typo.

Comment: Well spotted; fixed.

Comment: not sure if we might need to skip that iteration of the `for loop` when `$file` equals `standard.csv`.?